# Not able to send SqlDependency push notification to specific user using asp.net MVC SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a hub with a static method which broadcasts notifications to all users currently.

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
    public static void SendNotifications(string userId)
    {

        string connectionid = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == userId).ConnectionId;
        context.Clients.All.notify("added"); 
    }
}
```

It is working, but when I am broadcasting message to a specific user

```
[HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
    public static void SendNotifications(string userId)
    {

        string connectionid = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == userId).ConnectionId;
        context.Clients.Client(connectionid).notify("added"); 
    }
```

It is not working. I am invoking call to SendNotification from Following Method.

```
void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e, string EmpID)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            NotificationHub.SendNotifications(EmpID);
            RegisterNotification(DateTime.Now, EmpID);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Looks like the id you get is not a signalr connection id.

Comment: It is connection ID @Pawel, I am storing the user name and connection id into a static list.

Comment: Are you implementing all the hub connection events to keep your ConnectedUsers collection up to date? For example OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled) and OnConnected.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find the solution? Please advise in the comment.